# Get value from a php array

Tags: php

I have a shipping API which produces a variable called $quotereply.

print_r ($quotereply) gives me the following output:

```
Array ( [replycode] => 200 [replymessage] => success [replytype] => quote [quote] => Array ( [services] => Array ( [noofservices] => 2 [service1] => Array ( [name] => TestService1Before12am [description] => Test Service 1 Before 12am [carrier] => Camel [price] => 10 [vat] => 0 [vat_rate] => 0 [insurance_cost] => 0 [insurance_cover] => 0 ) [service2] => Array ( [name] => TestService2Anytime [description] => Test Service 2 Anytime [carrier] => Pigeon [price] => 5 [vat] => 0 [vat_rate] => 0 [insurance_cost] => 0 [insurance_cover] => 0 ) ) ) [custom] => Array ( [data] => [orderid] => ) )
```

My question is, how can I extract a value such as [noofservices] from this?  I can't really get my head round what I'm looking at, is it an array within an array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the formatted output instead of one long line, so we can see the nesting structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$quotereply['quote']['services']['noofservices']
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you, I'll accept the answer when the timer runs down!

Answer (score 0):

it is multidimensional array so you should follow `array` index keys]

```
echo $quotereply["quote"]["services"]["noofservices"];
```